# derivative of a function of vector norm with respect to vector

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, normed-spaces

folks.

I have been trying to figure out how to take a derivative of a function of vector norm with respect to vector.

Basically, I know the following basic derivatives.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bf r} \lvert\lvert \bf r \rvert\rvert = \frac{\bf r}{\lvert\lvert \bf r \rvert\rvert}\\$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bf r} \frac{\bf r}{\lvert\lvert \bf r \rvert\rvert}  = \frac{\bf I}{\lvert\lvert \bf r \rvert\rvert} - \frac{\bf r \otimes \bf r}{\lvert\lvert \bf r \rvert\rvert ^3}$

Starting from those, I want to know how to differentiate the following function with respect to vector,

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bf r} \frac{1}{\lvert\lvert f(\bf r) \rvert\rvert}  = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bf r} \frac{1}{\lvert\lvert \bf r \times (\bf r \times \bf r' ) \rvert\rvert}  = ?$

Thank you and it would be also appreciated if you can share the materials or text book that I can use to study advanced vector or tensor calculus?

Thank you.

Comment: What do $\times$ and $^\prime$ denote?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $\times$ means cross product of vectors and ' means a derivative with respect to arc-lengh s, meaning that $\bf r$ and $\bf r'$ are independent. Thank you!

Comment: OK. I figured it out.
$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \bf r} \frac{1}{\lvert\lvert f(\bf r) \rvert\rvert} = - \frac{(\frac{\partial f(\bf r)}{\partial \bf r})^{T} f(\bf r)}{\lvert\lvert f(\bf r) \rvert\rvert ^3}$